# How to use robocopy for selective file copying

Tags: robocopy

I am using omake for my project build
As part of my delivery build I need to copy some delivery related files into a folder

How I can use robocopy execution where I can only copy the interested files(which are selected by running a for loop on a list I have)
Into the folder.

List_paths = filepath1
Filepath2
.
FilepathN

For file in list_paths
%exec robocopy $(file,A) $(destin)
End for

By doing that robocopy always complains me that there is no such file by adding  \ at the end of eCh file and for destin folder too.

I Understand that robocopy just works fine for copying files from one folder to other but I have condition to copy only selective files from folders (for which I have the list of paths)

Please help on this.

Comment: `Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination [file [file]...] [options]` ?, So `ROBOCOPY dirfrom dirdest file1`

Comment: Hi Luuk Thank you. But is it possible that I can use a list of path names of each file for ex: I have a list which is running in FOR loop returns the absolute path name of each file so that it will be useful if I can pass that list variable in [file] section. And hence the copy will only be performed for the listed files inside FOR loop.

Comment: Please comment is it possible. %for file in list_path_files: %exec robocopy src dest $(file) %endfor

Answer (score 0):

If you have a textfile with complete patnames (i.e list.txt), with content:

```
d:\temp\a.sql
d:\temp\b.sql
d:\temp\c.sql
```

and a batchfile roboDo.bat like this:

```
@echo off

SET dest=d:\temp\temp\

FOR /f "useback tokens=1" %%f IN (`type list.txt`) DO (
    ECHO copying %%~nxf from %%~dpf to %dest%
    ROBOCOPY /NP /NJH /NJS %%~dpf %dest% %%~nxf >NUL
)
```

running the batchfile wil output this:

```
D:\TEMP>robodo
copying a.sql from d:\TEMP\ to d:\temp\temp\
copying b.sql from d:\TEMP\ to d:\temp\temp\
copying c.sql from d:\TEMP\ to d:\temp\temp\
```

Comment: #Looping through header files and copy to src/for_src folder
%foreach file_h in $(FOR_INCLUDE_FILES,A)
  %exec robocopy /MIR  $(FOR_INCLUDE_DIR) $(FOR_PROJECT_OUTPUT_DELIVERY_DIR)/ASM/src/for_src $(file_h,B,>.h)
%endfor

Comment: What kind of environment is that ?