# How to use robocopy to copy files from a folder folders (robocopy need to go through every subfolder and check for files)

Tags: robocopy, omake

```
#Looping through header files and copy to src/for_src folder
%foreach file_h in $(FOR_INCLUDE_FILES,A)
  %exec robocopy /MIR  $(FOR_INCLUDE_DIR) $(FOR_PROJECT_OUTPUT_DELIVERY_DIR)/ASM/src/for_src $(file_h,B,>.h)
%endfor
```

With the above lines i am trying to loop thru the list of files and trying to only copy the matching files of the list using robocopy.
The source directory is a mother folder inside two other folders were there namely asil and QM
My expectation is to search for the file in every iteration inside those sub folders and copy them to the destination folder.
Please help me on how to do copy only the matching files and search inside folder folders for the matching files.

Comment: This seems to be a followup on : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66076368/how-to-use-robocopy-for-selective-file-copying

Comment: That is a different question altogether. Kindly write your helpful comments only by considering the current question. thank you.